How does variant Encumbrance apply to Large creatures?
If you're playing a Large creature under the variant rule for Encumbrance from Chapter 7 of the Player's Handbook, at what point are you encumbered? Is it the same as for a Medium creature (over 5xSTR), or at double that weight (over 10xSTR)?

RAW, the encumbrance weight limits stay the same
The relevant rules are the following :

If you carry weight in excess of 5 times your Strength score, you are encumbered, [...]
If you carry weight in excess of 10 times your Strength score, up to your maximum carrying capacity, you are instead heavily encumbered, [...]

As written, the rules do not say anything about size, so it isn't a factor in this rule. As such, those limits for being encumbered or heavily encumbered are still respectively "5 times Strength" and "10 times Strength".
But this doesn't make any sense!
This optional rule clearly is designed based on the assumption that "15 times Strength" is your maximum carrying capacity, and then designates different encumbrance levels at respectively 1/3rd and 2/3rd of your maximum capacity.
It does not take into account any effect or condition that may affect this capacity, meaning that taken as written, no matter what happens to your carrying capacity, you are still encumbered the same way.
As correctly shown in your answer, it makes no sense for Tiny creatures, as they cannot ever be heavily encumbered (their maximum carrying capacity is lower than the capacity at which they're heavily encumbered), and only suffer from being encumbered while carrying more than 2/3rd of their maximum capacity.
And just the same, it makes no sense for Large or larger creatures, since as written, a Gargantuan creature is heavily encumbered when holding more than 1/12th of their maximum capacity. That's less than 9% of their total capacity!
Even ignoring the size rules, this means that any feature, item, spell or anything else that modifies your carrying capacity does not affect your encumbrance status. I can think of the Bear Totem Barbarian 6th level feature Aspect of the Beast, or the spell Enhance Ability with the option "Bull's Strength", but in any case the idea stays the same : abilities that help with carrying more do not help with encumbrance, which does not make sense and feels pointless.
A sane way to work around this rule?
I have never played with this optional rule, but the way this DM would rule it would be the way it seems to be intended from the start : 1/3rd and 2/3rd of your final carrying capacity, after applying all ongoing modifiers.
This makes the most immediate sense ("if I can carry more, I can carry more before suffering penalties") and gives more value to abilities which increase this capacity, which is most likely the reason why you want to use this rule.

In short: Variant rules are often only a gesture in the direction of what the rules ought to be and don't cover all the edge cases!

You don't double the weight: it's the same as for a Medium creature
Here are the relevant parts of the Lifting and Carrying and Variant: Encumbrance rules:

Your carrying capacity is your Strength score multiplied by 15....
You can push, drag, or lift a weight in pounds up to twice your carrying capacity (or 30 times your Strength score)...
For each size category above Medium, double the creature's carrying capacity and the amount it can push, drag, or lift. For a Tiny creature, halve these weights.
If you carry weight in excess of 5 times your Strength score, you are encumbered....
If you carry weight in excess of 10 times your Strength score, up to your maximum carrying capacity, you are instead heavily encumbered....

The Encumbrance rule doesn't say anything about size, and the limits in the Encumbrance rule are not defined in terms of carrying capacity. So for Large creatures you double your carrying capacity and amount you can lift/pull/drag, but not the limit above which you're encumbered or heavily encumbered. Here's an example for creatures of various sizes with a STR score of 10:



creature size
encumbered
heavily encumbered
carrying capacity
lift/pull/drag limit




Tiny
>50lb
--
75lb
150lb


Small/Medium
>50lb
>100lb
150lb
300lb


Large
>50lb
>100lb
300lb
600lb


Huge
>50lb
>100lb
600lb
1200lb


Gargantuan
>50lb
>100lb
1200lb
2400lb



Remember that the Encumbrance rule is intended to apply to player characters, which are not typically Large or larger. But of course you can have a Large PC, e.g. through the Enlarge/Reduce spell, and this is also relevant for Medium PCs with the Powerful Build trait.

Variant rules barely cover what they are intended for, extrapolating them for things they clearly don't cover is a bad idea.

As the current sole upvote here, I just want to point out that OP asked how the variant Encumbrance rule applied to Large creatures, and this answer explains that it doesn't, which is RAW correct.  OP did not ask whether it should apply or whether that makes sense, and I don't think this answer should be penalized for correctly answering the question.  If nothing else, this is a great demonstration of why the variant doesn't make sense at different sizes and its commentary that the rule is likely designed for Medium-size PCs only is well-taken.

@Kirt then we have a different reading, this answer says (to me) that it applies exactly the same no matter the creature size. There is a footnote about it not making sense, but the main answer isn't changed by that.

@SeriousBri  As cited, the Variant encumbrance rules say that creature size changes maximum capacities, but not values at which one is encumbered or heavily encumbered.  Both answers say that; this answer has a chart showing it.  Both answers say it doesn't make sense.  This answer says we shouldn't expect it to make sense because the encumbrance rules are designed for Medium PC's.  The other answer includes a suggestion for fixing it.  At least, that's my read.

The variant Encumbrance rule was poorly written and by RAW, this answer explained it all with a table showing how poorly written that rule was. Take my upvote. The solution @Mathieu included on his answer seems to be the most logical approach and probably (my view on this), what was supposed to be (RAI).
